# Use cylindrical shell to find volume

Tags: integration, volume

Use cylindrical shell to find volume of solid
When $y=x^2$ , $x=1$ , $y=0$
about the x-axis
Thanks all

Comment: And what have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: V=  the integral from 0 to 1 of $2{pi}$*$y(y^(1/2))$ = $4pi/5$ but the right answer is pi/5 and I tried to solve it by washer and it is correct but not cylindrical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the volume of a cylindrical shell is : 2*pi*radius*height = 2*pi*y*(1 - y^1/2). So V = Int(0-->1)[2*pi*y(1 - y^1/2)] = pi/5